# Angular 6 router.navigate() queryParams parser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm facing an issue while developing an application using Angular 6. While passing an object as a value of a property of `queryParams: { prop: value}`, built in function converts object to a string, and I get an usual in js `[object Object]`.

What I'm trying to do:
I have a query string that i use to send request to my server. I want to use it now, to update query params of current route. Example of my query string stringified with npm-qs lib:

```
?priceRange[min]=1&priceRange[max] = 2
```

Let's take a look at my object that I parse with the same lib, back to an object:

```
priceRange: {min: "1", max: "2"}
```

What `queryParams` converts it to:

```
priceRange=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

To do so, I parse it back to a proper object, and then, I use a method posted somewhere here:

```
constructor(
  private readonly router: Router,
  private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

updateQueryParams() {
  this.router.navigate([], {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    queryParams: {
      priceRange: {min: "1", max: "2"} (hardcoded this to simplify example)
    }
 });
}
```

With the code above I'm trying to:

1. Stay at the same page (`[]` along with `relativeTo: this.activatedRoute`, makes me to stay at the same page as far as I understand);
2. Change url to `.com/?priceRange[min]=1&priceRange[max]=2` (or something like that)

I'm asking, is there a way to use objects as a values in queryParams, or are there any suggestions? I've read through angular.io docs, there is nothing about such case, just simple examples of `param1=q & param2=w`, same actually in several stack posts. Maybe I can somehow pass a query string to my url using Angular means? (Not using those `queryParams` of `router.navigate()` method).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this `%5Bobject%20Object%5D` but then I understood the reason.
This is because query params need to be passed as a second argument.

As shown below:

```
this.router.navigate(["/enter-url"], { 
  queryParams: { 
    priceRange: {
      min: "1",
      max: "2"
    }
  } 
});
```